# Do I need concurrency control on python array if no 2 threads access the same element?

Tags: python, concurrency

I have a large python array (and by array I mean a list that is initialized to a certain size by doing [None] * 1000) that will be accessed by multiple threads. No 2 threads will ever access the same index. Do I need any sort of concurrency control? I'm guessing not since there's no threat of overwriting values? Thanks!

Comment: What concurrency solution are you using? lib/threading's GIL (global interpreter lock), which uses faux-threads shouldn't have any problems. Otherwise, if using multiprocessing or similar, you may need to use specific constructs. More info?

Comment: I'm using the multiprocessing module on python 2.7.2

Comment: If you are using multiprocessing, how do you handle sharing the memory?

Comment: I should have read more about multiprocessing. Looks like I will have to use multiprocessing's Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between having no shared array elements between threads and the GIL, you're good.